# .push leading to undefined values in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am unsure why this code is returning undefined values in the 'group' arrays:

```
Arr = [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0]
for (j=0; j<5; j++){
    for (i in Arr) {
        this["groupS" + j + "C" + i] = [Arr[i]]
        for (a=1; a<=j; a++) {
            this["groupS" + j + "C" + i].unshift(Arr[i-a])
            this["groupS" + j + "C" + i].push(Arr[i+a])
        }
    }
}
console.log(groupS2C2)
```

It returns `[0, 0, 1, undefined, undefined]` for the group that should contain the first 5 elements of `Arr`. For some reason, it seems to be working with negating 'a' but not with adding 'a'.

Comment: Before I can answer a question I need to see whee and how `CA` is defined, and what is your context, what does `this` refer too, is it global object, local object, function, class instance?

Comment: Oh I didn't update that.. where it says CA should be Arr (I tested it before I changed the other CA's to Arr's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `for (i in Arr)` because `Arr` is not an object, it is an array.
You must use an index for arrays, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++)
```

---

**EDIT:** technically, `Arr` *is* an object, but treating it as such, is not what you intended. That's why you still get partially correct results.

Comment: Brilliant! This has solved my issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: You surely can use `for(i in Arr)` with arrays, but (and this is the OP's problem), `i` would be a property name, and hence a string.